# Install Grails on Windows 10

Tags: windows, grails

I am trying to install Grails on Windows, which is an easy process. But, I got an error which I can't understand its reason? I configure java home and grails home properly. Any idea why grails isn't installed?

```
C:\Users\admin>java -version
java version "14" 2020-03-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14+36-1461)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14+36-1461, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Users\admin>echo %grails_home%
C:\grails-4.0.0

C:\Users\admin>grails -version
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.VMPluginFactory.<clinit>(VMPluginFactory.java:43)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GroovyClassValueFactory.<clinit>(GroovyClassValueFactory.java:35)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.<clinit>(ClassInfo.java:107)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.getCachedClass(ReflectionCache.java:95)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.<clinit>(ReflectionCache.java:39)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.registerMethods(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:209)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:107)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:85)
        at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:36)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:86)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.bitwiseNegate(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:842)
        at org.grails.config.NavigableMap.<clinit>(NavigableMap.groovy)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.<clinit>(GrailsCli.groovy:77)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgmimpl.NumberNumberMetaMethod.<clinit>(NumberNumberMetaMethod.java:33)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:124)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:346)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:604)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.createMetaMethodFromClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:257)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:110)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:85)
        at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:36)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:86)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.bitwiseNegate(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:842)
        at org.grails.config.NavigableMap.<clinit>(NavigableMap.groovy)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.<clinit>(GrailsCli.groovy:77)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using JDK14 which is not supported by grails 4.0.x. Use a LTS such as Java 11. wait until grails updates to the latest

Spring-boot, which Grails is based on, [added support for JDK 14](https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/26/spring-boot-2-2-6-available-now) 4 days ago (March 26th 2020). JDK 14 will likely be supported in Grails 4.1.x series.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you think which versions (JDK and grails) I should use?

Comment: I would recommend Java 11 as it's the latest Long Term Support (TLS) and Grails 4.0.2 (latest)

Comment: It would be nice if the Grails 4 documentation mentioned this.